# Uniqueness of moments for probability distributions with infinite moments.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was taught the collection of a distribution's moments uniquely defined the distribution. Recently, I have been studying Pareto distributions, which have infinite means for shape parameters less than 1. It was also my understanding that if a moment of rank $\rho$ does not converge, all moments of rank greater than $\rho$ will also not converge. As such, for a Pareto distribution with shape $\alpha$ less than 1, its moments are:

$moment = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \infty & : order \ge 1\\
       1 &      : order = 0
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$

The moments are identical for multiple different Pareto distributions, violating my initial statement, a contradiction.

Could anyone help point out where my lack of understanding lies?

Edit: fixed some notation

Comment: The distribution uniquely defines the moments.  It does _not_ go the other direction.

Comment: From wolfram|alpha: moments do not define the distribution http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Moment.html.


 
And from wikipedia: moments do uniquely define the Distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29

Can someone help me make sense of this?

Comment: the statement in Wikipedia is about Borel measure with **compact support**

Comment: @user251257, is your comment in reference to the second paragraph of the introduction of that article? Or somewhere else within?

Comment: yes. the uniqueness result seems only be valid for compactly supported Borel measure. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem

Comment: Fascinating. Things I was taught in basic probability classes seem to have an alarming propensity to be wrong (i.e: Central Limit Theorem, this question). Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the right distribution from [moments is a tricky business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem). First off, the sequence of moments has to be valid. You can see a technical condition involving Hankel matrices in the link. Basically, it says you can't just write down an arbitrary sequence of numbers and claim they are moments of some distribution. In your case, the moments actually come from a distribution, so you don't have to worry about this.

In the case that *all* moments exist (are finite), then there are two subcases. If your distribution is supported on a finite interval $[a,b]$ then there is a unique measure that corresponds to them. If the interval is infinite, then the measure is *not* necessarily unique. You need an extra condition, something like [Carleman's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_condition) to guarantee uniqueness.

Finally, there's your case, which is a truncated moment problem: you only have existence of the first $k$ moments. This problem has even less uniqueness. This is because you can cook up plenty of distributions, such as power laws that look like $d/(1+a(x-b)^c)$ which can sometimes match all your moments. In your example, take $1/(1+|x-1|^3),$ which has mean 1 but no second moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-to-one correspondence between distributions that
have moment generating functions (MGFs) and their MGFs. But not
every distribution has an MGF (and some have MGFs that are
not of practical use because of analytic difficulties).

If you
have a particular MGF, you can be sure only one distribution matches
that MGF.

By taking the $k$th derivative $m_X^{[k]}(t)$ of the MGF of $X$ and setting $t = 0$
you get $E(X^k) = m_X^{[k]}(0).$ Conversely, if you know
all of the moments $E(X), E(X^2), \dots,$ you can use them
to write a Taylor series that is equal to $m_X(t).$ (See Wikipedia
on 'moment generating function' in the Definition section.)

It is in that sense that some texts say that a distribution
is uniquely specified by its moments. However, in practice,
I do not think this is often a useful way to identify a distribution.

Note: Outside of statistics and probability MGFs are called Laplace transforms. Characteristic functions (Fourier transforms) exist
for all distributions, and they can also be used to find moments,
but are somewhat more advanced mathematically than MGFs. I'm guessing
it is the connections among MGFs, distributions, and moments, as explained above, that prompted your question.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. You explanation makes sense to me, however, on its Wikipedia page, it looks to me like the Pareto distribution is said to have an MGF (no restrictions on parameters are shown). Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution
There is a restriction on what is called $t$, but this $t$ is not defined and I do not know what it represents (when I was doing MGF's in class, a varialbe $t$ was what we differentiated the function with respect to, and subsequently set to zero in order to get the moment).

Comment: Wikipedia is often useful, but I would not depend on the $summary$ table at the beginning of the article to be totally complete in every detail. When it says the mean does not exist for certain values of the shape parameter, I think you have to understand that restriction applies to the MGF also. (Also, my practice is to double check anything from an online source.)

Comment: All of that makes sense. Your answer and Alex's have not only answered my question, but helped further understand my knowledge of the subject in general. I would accept both as the answer if I could. But I can't, so I flipped a coin. Thanks again for taking the time to answer

Comment: For your mathematical level, I think your coin came up the right way.